# Embedded Resource Style XAML file not found at runtime. works in design time.

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, styles

I have a CommonResources.xaml in my project with a build action of `Embedded Resource`. I have added this to `mycustomcontrol.xaml` using the below code.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyApp;Component/Resources/CommonResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This works perfectly at design time and my styles are applied as required.

However at runtime i get the following exception.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: '/MyApp;Component/Resources/CommonResources.xaml' 
value cannot be assigned to property 'Source' of object 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary'. 
Cannot locate resource 'resources/commonresources.xaml'.  Error at object 
'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary' in markup file
'MyApp;component/application/controls/mycustomcontrol.xaml' Line 18 Position 37.
```

I dont know why this is failing at runtime. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use Embedded Resource as build action, swap it to just Resource.

Comment: @ChrisW. I tried that but there is a huge amount of code that breaks when i do this. I need it to remain as an Embedded Resource.

Comment: Go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178(v=vs.100).aspx) and ctrl+f "Do not use embedded resource"